# Find elements by multiple names jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have these 4 checkboxes and I want to find them in jQuery by their names.
Is there any way to find all 4 checkboxes by their name?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="RangeFlexionRightSide1" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="RangeFlexionRightSide2" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="ManualFlexionRightSide1" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="ManualFlexionRightSide2" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
```

I am trying these below codes but I didn't get the result:

```
$("input[name^='Range Manual']").length

$("input[name^='Range,Manual']").length

$("input[name^='Range'][name^='Manual']").length
```

Comment: `$("input[name$='FlexionRightSide']")` should get the inputs whose `name` ends in `FlexionRightSide`. You could also add a class to these elements to make it easier to select them

Comment: You should consider adding a common class to simplify the selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you could use the ending by selector `$=` like :

```
$("input:checkbox[name$='FlexionRightSide']").length
```

Or using start with selctor `^=` like :

```
$("input:checkbox[name^='Range'],input:checkbox[name^='Manual']").length
```

**NOTE :** You could give them a common class, and select them easely using class selector `.` like :

```
$('.common_class').length
```

```js
console.log($("input:checkbox[name$='FlexionRightSide']").length); //4
console.log($("input:checkbox[name^='Range'],input:checkbox[name^='Manual']").length); //4
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="RangeFlexionRightSide1" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="RangeFlexionRightSide2" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="ManualFlexionRightSide1" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="ManualFlexionRightSide2" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
```

Comment: Yes it is working properly but I wanted to find by starting characters only. Because I have just posted 4 check boxes whereas in my page there are 300 check boxes with prefix 'Range' and 'manual'.

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `*=` which will check if name contains value passed.

Or you can do as your way with `^=` as shown below.

In jQuery selectors

- `[name^='Range']` - Here `^=` find element whose `name` starts with `Range`.
- `[name$='Range']` - Here `$=` find element whose `name` ends with `Range`.
- `[name*='Range']` - Here `*=` find element whose `name` contains `Range`.

Find more about [jQuery Selector here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

```js
console.log($("input[name^='Range'], input[name^='Manual']").length);
console.log($("input[name*='RightSide']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="RangeFlexionRightSide1" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="RangeFlexionRightSide2" name="RangeFlexionRightSide">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="ManualFlexionRightSide1" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="ManualFlexionRightSide2" name="ManualFlexionRightSide">
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you need:

```
$("input[name^='Range'],input[name^='Manual']").length
```